# Understanding the --include argument to grep

Tags: bash, unix, grep, full-text-search

Can someone explain why I'm getting the following output when I make this call to `grep`?

```
dbliss@nx5[~]> grep -rnwl --include=ardid.sh.e* . -e "pkg_resources"
grep: ./.pulse/a319a33547084e303e0286aa00000023-runtime: Permission denied
grep: ./.pulse/2d3380c658b942aac267d6570000001f-runtime: Permission denied
grep: ./.pulse/d1aa29d3e0e227d33d032c9f00000020-runtime: Permission denied
grep: ./.pulse/e7a8f36648b96d90ecbddd2f00000018-runtime: Permission denied
grep: ./.pulse/922bdeb7e34db855d003e2fd00000019-runtime: Permission denied
grep: ./.pulse/2e970606c3a2bfa06aa690e600000018-runtime: Permission denied
grep: ./.pulse/c113767245ecdc7cb59125af00000017-runtime: Permission denied
grep: ./.pulse/0202df89e10e160883b6aa8200000021-runtime: Permission denied
```

I'm attempting to limit the search to files that match the pattern `ardid.sh.e*` -- i.e., start with `ardid.sh.`, followed by any number of other characters.  But the output shows that a bunch of files in the `.pulse` directory were searched that do not include `ardid` in their names.

If this is the wrong call to be making, what call should I be making?

Comment: Are those files or directories? Are they symlinks?

Comment: @EtanReisner aha, they are directories.  that answers my question.  i had assumed they were files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that those are, in fact files, and not directories or symlinks.

grep might be attempting to access them to search for files that match your pattern and failing despite your `--include` argument.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely that output is *not* part of the standard output `grep` produces, but of standard *error* output. `grep` has to access the file content to scan for the search pattern. For that it requires read permission to files and permission to enter directories. It posts that report per file or directory if it fails to gain access.

You can easily test that yourself if you simply drop the error output to get back *only* standard out:

```
grep -rnwl --include=ardid.sh.e* . -e "pkg_resources" 2 > /dev/null
```

Probably the output of that command will not show those entries any more...

Comment: the issue is that those files (if they were files) should not be searched at all.  the answer is that they aren't files -- they're directories.

Comment: That makes sense, indeed. At least I have the honor of pointing into the right direction. Have fun!